# How to include files in my Git commit with PHPStorm?

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm, commit

#### Reworded question:

I use the PHPStorm IDE. During my development process I add images for testing purposes. I want to include them in my commits, so other team members can see and pull them from the repo. How do I do that? Can I configure PHPStorm to do that for me?

#### Original question:

*phpstorm vcs (GIT) dont upload images*
First of all, sorry for my English. I will try to do my best. :D

I want to know how can i configure PHPStorm to upload the images in every commit (git)... Like Sourcetree does.

For example, if i have a gallery module in my app and i upload some image to test, when i make a commit for my team they cant see the image because phpstorm does not uploaded it. Atlassian Sourcetree does but i want to use the built in VCS from PHPStorm..

Comment: are you excluding image out of working directory? see your .gitignore

Comment: Nope... images folder is not in the .gitgnore file. for some reason, the built-ni vcs dont upload any image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 9 does.. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

**Why I think there's no configuration needed.**

PHPStorm and any other IDE is just a tool to manage your git repo. You can work with the same repo from IDE, any GUI-tool and command-line simultaneously. Your question seems to be about Git and not about IDE configuration.

**What one can and can't add to a commit.**

Second, Git can only work with files that are in the directory, where you've initiated a Git repo. Usually it's your project's root directory. If you add your images to a directory somewhere in your project - you can add them to commit. If they are somewhere else, you'll have to download them and put somewhere in the project. I could not understand that clearly from your question.

**Just tell me how to add my files!**

Now, when the files are somewhere in your project folder, you can add them:

1. From PHPStorm. Pick the file, menu [VCS] >> [Git] >> [Add]
2. From the console. Press Alt+F12 to open the console. Then

`git status` to see lists of files (1) changed and staged for commit (2) changed but not staged, (3) not tracked yet. Any list may be empty.

`git add full/path/to/file.png` to add the files to next commit

`git commit -m'commit message'` or your usual way to commit files from IDE menu

Please reply whether it helps or not.

Comment: Thank you Nick, yes i know that PHPStorm is only and IDE working with an external app called git but SourceTree is the same thing... It is just a graphic user interface for git. Sourcetree scan all my project, see the new changes and upload it all, incluiding images, why phpstorm doen't?, it is imposible or i need a configurataion?

Comment: oh... almost forgot... The image folder is into the project directory. I am woking in laravel, so, the folder image is in project>public>images

Comment: maybe SourceTree automatically commits all changes that it sees? IDEs by IntelliJ only add files and commit if you explicitely make them do it.

Comment: Ok, understood about the path to images.

Comment: In phpstorm you just need to 1) manually add the files for the next commit; 2) make that commit. If you want phpstorm to automatically scan and add all changes... well, some day you may accidentally commit some trash or delete a file.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. I will do that manually then... that's a worderful feature from attlasian. I have to get used to PHPStorm xDDD

Comment: In my opinion, manual approach is better, because it gives you control. A commit is done when there's some meaning to all those commited files. If a file is a part of that meaning - include it. If it's just some unfinished chunk of code that doesn't compile, or a binary that accidentally fell into some folder - It shouldn't be a part of commit.